# Laravel whereDate() not working when trying to fetch records between two dates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I use the following query to get the records between two dates. I Entered 2017-05-01 in From Date, 2017-05-30 in To Date. I Run the Query and get Empty Results. but, This DB table have Many Records for this Month. I Remove Dates Query after Run It, It's Get Many Records. What's My Problem..

```
    $getdatewiseresults = Companyledger::whereDate('transaction_date', '<=' , $data['frmdate_submit'])
    ->whereDate('transaction_date', '>=', $data['todate_submit'])
    ->WhereIn('frm_ledger', $ledgerlist)
    ->where('company_id' ,$companyids)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$getdatewiseresults = Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->where('company_id',$companyids);
if(!empty($data['todate_submit'])) {
    $getdatewiseresults = $getdatewiseresultsget->whereBetween('transaction_date', [$data['frmdate_submit'], $data['todate_submit']]);
} else {
    $getdatewiseresults = $getdatewiseresultsget->whereDate('transaction_date', '=', $data['frmdate_submit']);
}

$getdatewiseresults = $getdatewiseresults->get();
```

Comment: if Todate got Empty Value.. what i Do... @SK Jajoriya

Answer (score 0):

Your date check is wrong, you're doing the opposite of what you want. Also use carbon to parse your dates so that you don't have to worry about date formats. Check the code below.

```
$fromDate = $data['frmdate_submit'];
$toDate = $data['todate_submit'];

$getdatewiseresults = Companyledger::where('company_id', $companyids)
    ->whereIn('frm_ledger', $ledgerlist)
    ->where('transaction_date', '>=' , \Carbon\Carbon::parse($fromDate))
    ->where('transaction_date', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($toDate))
    ->get();
```

Also from the comments you requested to apply the dates only when given. Use this to apply the date conditions only if they're provided.

```
$getdatewiseresults = Companyledger::where('company_id', $companyids)
    ->whereIn('frm_ledger', $ledgerlist)
    ->when($fromDate, function ($query) use ($fromDate) {
        return $query->where('transaction_date', '>=' , \Carbon\Carbon::parse($fromDate));
    })
    ->when($toDate, function ($query) use ($toDate) {
        return $query->where('transaction_date', '<=' , \Carbon\Carbon::parse($toDate));
    })
    ->get();
```